# How to enable back button in android webview

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have been trying to enable the back button for a particular `webview` app that I am working on but it's actually not working for me.

I have tried all the codes I found on stack overflow but I still find it hard to make my code work.

below is my code

here is the **mainactivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.pluxscore.com.ng");
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView != null && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();// if there is previous page open it
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();//if there is no previous page, close app
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the **Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you get any error or something?

Comment: If the issue you are seeing is that pressing the back button always closes the app, then I think the problem is that you are never assigning anything to the `webView` field. As a result, the `webView` field is always `null` when the user presses the back button.